# how to keep line feed in result returned by bash command

Tags: bash

let's say, I can rsh to machine XXX as user foo, then after executing:

```
$result=$(rsh -l foo XXX "ls");
echo $result;
```

I found that the line feed is removed in the result, and I can't see the result in a line by line way. so what I should do if I'd like to have the line feed int the returned result?

Comment: You should not have a dollar sign in front of the varible name when you assign to it.  `rsh=$(rsh -l foo XXX "ls")`.  The terminating semicolons are redundant but harmless.

Answer (score 5):

The newline is there; the error is in using `echo` to examine it (without double quotes around the variable, too!)

```
result=$(rsh -l foo XXX "ls")
echo "$result"
```

In trivial cases, you can get away without quotes, but the interesting cases might even contain [security issues.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/171346/security-implications-of-forgetting-to-quote-a-variable-in-bash-posix-shells)

If you are only capturing the standard output of `rsh` so that you can print it to standard output yourself, this is a [useless use of `echo`](http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#echo)

Comment: Probably also prefer `ssh` over `rsh` and [don't use `ls` in scripts.](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

Answer (score 1):

Edit: If you mean the newlines between each file, just make sure to quote the result:

```
result="$(rsh -l foo XXX "ls");"
```

This will keep any characters *except* NUL (`$'\0'`), which can't be stored in a Bash variable.

If you mean that the **trailing newline** is lost, then this is the simplest solution I know:

```
resultx="$(commands...; echo x)"
result="${resultx%x}"
```