# In Bash, how do I pass the output of the first command to a command line argument of the second?

Tags: bash

For example:

```
mycommand.py -a `cat myfile.json`
```

In this example, I need the contents of `myfile.json` to be passed as the value to the `-a` argument of `mycommand.py`. This *almost* works, but I need the file contents (which include double quotes and newlines) to be surrounded by quotes. This *does not* work:

```
mycommand.py -a '`cat myfile.json`'
```

The use of the single quotes prevents the backtick quotes from working.

Comment: homework problem?

Answer (score 3):

Use double quotes.

```
mycommand.py -a "`cat myfile.json`"
```

Comment: Dang!  You type faster than I do!  As long as I’ve got an extra 42 seconds, let me suggest changing that to `mycommand.py -a "$(cat myfile.json)"`.

Comment: Thanks. This is so obvious I almost feel like I should delete the question...

Comment: Oh, probably somebody will do a search and discover that an equivalent question has been asked and answered before, and then this one will be closed as a duplicate.

Comment: I looked around.. it's kind of a hard one to search for.

Comment: It's hard to search for something when you don't know what it's called (`command substitution` for future reference).

Comment: A search through Super User questions for “bash quote” yielded [How to keep line feed in result returned by bash command](http://superuser.com/questions/399685/how-to-keep-line-feed-in-result-returned-by-bash-command), which is fairly similar.